# What is the difference between a transcriptome and a genome?

Tags: genome, transcriptome

I have a computer engineering background, not biology.

I started working on a bioinformatics project recently, which involves *de-novo* assembly. I came to know the terms `Transcriptome` and `Genome`, but I cannot identify the difference between these two.

I know a transcriptome is the set of all messenger RNA molecules in a cell, but am not sure how this is different from a genome.

Comment: What information have you researched ? Did Wikipedia pages of Transcriptome and Genome helped you? If not where they didn't help you

Comment: This is a rather basic question and I don't think it's a good one for the site, in the message from stack exchange it says "if you ask beginner questions, survey questions, or social-conversation questions, experts and pros will not be interested"

Comment: This is not a bioinformatics question, this is a terminology question and needs to be be better framed. The approaches to transcriptome and genome de novo assembly would be accceptable, but this is a question for Google.

Comment: You can vote to close the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In brief, the  “genome”  is the collection of all  DNA  present  in  the  nucleus  and  the  mitochondria of a  somatic  cell. The initial product of genome expression is the “transcriptome”, a collection of RNA molecules derived from those genes.

Comment: If you want to learn more about relationships between these terms, see this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_dogma_of_molecular_biology).

Comment: This is a good concise answer.

Answer (score 5):

They are two very different things. Your genome is a large section of about 3 billion DNA nucleotide bases. It has no concept of exon and introns.

Transcriptome is a study of [transcriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(biology)). You have introns and exons. We can now talk about alternative splicing and gene expression.

You can think your genome is like a cooking recipe. While it's good to have a good recipe, you can't do much if you don't use it for cooking.

Comment: I like to compare the genome with the cookbook, the transcriptome with your shopping lists, the proteome with your groceries.

Comment: wouldn't the proteome be the cooked food?